# Use checkbox dynamically added to userform

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I add `CheckBox1` to my `UserForm` with this code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim opt As Variant
    Set opt = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.checkbox.1", "CheckBox1", True)
End Sub
```

Now when I click on a `CommandButton` I want to Check if the `CheckBox1` is checked or not:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If CheckBox1.Value = False Then
        MsgBox "F"
    End If
End Sub
```

But this code doesn't work; I think because the check box is added dynamically.
This is just a simplification of the code for solving the problem.

Comment: You could also create opt as a Module variable rather than a Sub variable? Put `Private opt As Control` just after your `Option Explicit` and remove `Dim opt As Variant`, then you can use `If Not opt.Value Then MsgBox "F"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you are thinking of:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim opt As Variant
    Set opt = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.checkbox.1", "CheckBox1", True)
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If Not Me.Controls("CheckBox1") Then
        MsgBox "F"
    End If
End Sub
```

---

**However**, depending on your experience and desires to write better code, you may decide to follow some MVC pattern in working with Forms. Read these for some more ideas about it:

- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/154401/handling-dialog-closure-in-a-vba-user-form
- http://www.vitoshacademy.com/vba-the-perfect-userform-in-vba/ (Disclaimer - this is my blog)
- https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/

Answer (score 0):

It will need to be as follows

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If Me.Controls("Checkbox1").Value = False Then
MsgBox "F"
End If
End Sub
```